# Is there a way for client to send server data on socket disconnection?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Is it possible for client to send a socket data when it gets 
disconnected (user closes the browser, or tab)? 
Because, I found that default bind on disconnect doesn't take any input data.

```js
//on server side 
socket.on('disconnect',function(){ 
    //in other binds, it takes 'data' as an input but this does not 
});
```

I tried to resolve this problem by using the jQuery's unload method 
like below

```js
//on client side 
$(window).unload(function(){ 
    socket.emit('depart','I am leaving'); 
});
```

However, it does not seem to emit at all on unload. (maybe `socket` gets out of scope on unload?)
Is there a way to send data through websocket to the server when client disconnects?

Secondly, Is there any way that I can store a string data in socket? For instance, 
`socket.userName = userNameVar;`

--update--
Here is how I set up environment on the serverside

```js
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('depart',function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log("user left");
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log("user disconnected");
    });
});
```

and following code is in the client side.

```js
var socket = io.connect(hostVar);

$(window).unload(function(){ 
    socket.emit('depart','I am leaving'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot send data on disconnect is because you are disconnected.  What you are asking is somewhat akin to saying "Can i still talk to the person on the phone after they've hung up on me?"

If you want to emit the 'depart' event, then you still have to capture it inside your 'connect' handler on server side:

As in:

```
io.socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('depart', function(msg) {
            // you should get depart message here

      });
})
```

Your depart event will come BEFORE the connection is terminated. disconnect is only raised by server upon a successful disconnection and therefore it cannot receive any messages.

Give it a try and tell me if this works :)

Comment: Yes I did that, but jQuery.unload event won't send that data... I will more codes on update

Comment: hmmm is your socket object still functional at that stage? do an alert(socket.toString()) to see if the object is still there.

Comment: Apparently, alert does not show up...Guess there is a problem in my code somewhere.. I will look for that

Comment: Okay, when I tested it in Chrome plus, it does not show `alert` msg, but Firefox seems to execute the code well. However, even using the Firefox, the socket does not seem to emit `depart` msg to the server.

Comment: try to see if you can emit socket somewhere else in the jQuery on an other event.

Comment: Yes I can emit socket somewhere else in jQuery. For instance, when button is clicked I can send socket like below `$('#button').click(function(){socket.emit('click','button clicked');});`

Comment: If I can save data on `socket` than I wouldn't need to worry about this, because I can just use the data in `socket` to display some message....

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',()=>{
        socket.emit('page_unload');
});
```

and on server side

```
io.socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('page_unload', function(msg) {
            // client has reloaded page or closed page
      });
})
```

Comment: Could add more details please.